# TopoJson map do not render in react-simple-map module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to add TopoJson Map to my  tag with URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soncomqiq/front-end-forensic/master/gadm36_THA_1.json is not working

But If I add the URL: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GordyD/49654901b07cb764c34f/raw/27eff6687f677c984a11f25977adaa4b9332a2a9/countries-and-states.json
It's work.

I don't why my map does not be rendered.

my gadm36_THA_1.json is generated by the following steps(in step 6)
https://medium.com/@augustgiles8/rendering-the-us-with-react-simple-maps-2e31fe7d49d

```
<ZoomableGroup center={[-8.3, -46.8]} disablePanning>
        <Geographies geography="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soncomqiq/front-end-forensic/master/gadm36_THA_1.json">
          {(geographies, projection) =>
            geographies.map((geography, i) =>
              <Geography...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I know why my map didn't render.
actually, my map did render but I configured the center and scale wrong. It rendered but It was out of frame.